# Trouble with code to loop through named sheets and copy values from each sheet into seperate row in array and paste full array into master workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a code that will loop through a series of named worksheets, in each worksheet specific noncontinuous cells must be copied into a single 2D array where each worksheet is on a different row. Then I would like to insert the array into a different workbook.

I have some data that is scattered throughout several worksheets. The data is in the same cells in each worksheet. I would like to copy the data into another workbook with the data from each worksheet in different rows.

My code is shown below:

```
Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim fd As Office.FileDialog                                 
    Dim bb As Workbook                                        
    Dim cs As Worksheet     
    Dim bb As Workbook                                         
    Dim cs As Worksheet
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim compiledvalues(11, 7) As Variant
    Dim openbook As Variant
    Dim sheetname As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    With fd
        .Filters.Clear
        .Title = "Select Buildbook"
        .Filters.Add "Excel Files", "*.xlsm", 1 'only show macro-enabled excel docs
        .AllowMultiSelect = False   'don't allow multiple files to be selected
        .InitialFileName = "\C:Users\hsa\shared\"
        .Show   'show dialog box
        bbpath = .SelectedItems(1)

    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

     Set bb = Workbooks.Open(bbpath, True, True)
    openbook = Array ("Jan", "Feb", March, "April", "May","June","July", "August", "September", "October", "December")

    i=0

    For Each sheetname In openbook
            compiledvalues(i, 0) = ActiveSheet.Range("B26")
            compiledvalues(i, 1) = ActiveSheet.Range("C16")
            compiledvalues(i, 2) = ActiveSheet.Range("C15")
            compiledvalues(i, 3) = ActiveSheet.Range("D15")
            compiledvalues(i, 4) = ActiveSheet.Range("E36")
            compiledvalues(i, 5) = ActiveSheet.Range("F37")
            compiledvalues(i, 6) = ActiveSheet.Range("G16")
            compiledvalues(i, 7) = ActiveSheet.Range("G15")
            i = i + 1
    Next sheetname

    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    nextrow = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Compiled Data").Range("C3:C").Find(What:="*", After:=Range("A1"), SearchORder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row + 1
    Worksheets("Compiled Data").Activate
    ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(nextrow, 3), Cells(nextrow + 11, 10)) = compiledvalues

    bb.close
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you explain in more detail the "trouble" you are having? Does the code throw an error, for example, and if so on what line?

Comment: Have you dimensioned `compiledvalues`?  Note that if you want to append to a 2D array, you can *only* redimension the second element, e.g., `Redim compiledvalues(7,1)   //   Redim Preserve compiledvalues(7,1+1)`.  That will also dictate how you can use the data, e.g., `destWS.cells(3,1) =  compiledvalues(1,3)`

Comment: There are no quotes on your file path - your code as posted can't compile, which is often a sign there may be other differences between what you posted and what you're actually running.  Please take a look and edit your question if needed (you can also add in the array dimensioning)

Comment: Your code looks OK - are you getting an error?